# NodeJS require for async tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I am trying to use NodeJS require syntax with an asynchronous database query. I would like the program to wait for the query to complete before it moves on to the next require as some information returned from the database is passed as a parameter to the next require.

Here is my code:

```
const dealership = require('../models/getDealershipById.js')(id);
const dealershipLeads = require('../models/getLeadsByDealershipId.js')(dealership.id);
const dealershipStaff = require('../models/getStaffByDealershipId.js')(dealership.id);

return [dealership, dealershipLeads, dealershipStaff];
```

I have tried wrapping this in an anonymous async function but this did not work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my module code:

```
module.exports = function(id) {
const pool = require('../loaders/pool.js')();

  pool.query('SELECT * FROM dealerships WHERE id = \'' + id + '\';', (err, 
res) 
  => {
    if(err) console.error(err.stack);

    return res.rows[0];
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you have wrapped your exported function with `async` and `await`:

```
module.exports = function(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const pool = require('../loaders/pool.js')();

        pool.query(
            "SELECT * FROM dealerships WHERE id = '" + id + "';",
            (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.stack);
                    reject(err);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(res.rows[0]);
                }
            }
        );
    });
};
```

So now just use the `async` and `await` in the calling code:

```
async function getData() {
     const dealership = await require('../models/getDealershipById.js')(id);
     const dealershipLeads = await require('../models/getLeadsByDealershipId.js')(dealership.id);
     const dealershipStaff = await require('../models/getStaffByDealershipId.js')(dealership.id);
}

getData()
```

**Important**: as a side note, avoid `"SELECT * FROM dealerships WHERE id = '" + id + "';"` as this is a real bad security antipattern, if the `id` is not sanitized correctly it could very easily allow SQL code injection. Use something like `pool.query("SELECT * FROM dealerships WHERE id = ?", [id], ...)` if your driver allows it, or replace it with a driver or wrapper that does.

Comment: There's no point in using the `async` keyword if you only have a single line of code in the question. Just return the promise that `db.getCollection('foo').find({ id }).toArray()` returns directly (assuming it *does* return a promise, otherwise this won't work anyway).

Comment: You're right, but I assume the required JS files will have more processing than just returning the promise straight away. Otherwise, just return the original promise and no need for async/await inside the required module.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, I am using callbacks (I've updated the question with my module code). Do you know how to do it using callbacks?

Comment: Yes, I've just edited my answer to reflect that. Also read the important note at the end!